# How do I get a custom Monero address?

Tags: address

I've seen people with custom addresses on Monero, like having short custom three or four letter words in the beginning of the 95-character string. How do I get one of these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a vanity address generator. As far as I know, this one written in Go is the best/only available one:

https://github.com/ehmry/monero-vanity

Edit: there is another one here implemented in JavaScript, see generate address with prefix:

https://moneroaddress.org

Comment: What about the "Generate Wallet with Prefix" option here? moneroaddress.org

Comment: Ohyea, that one should work too. If guess Go is probably significantly faster than JavaScript, but haven't tested either of them to be honest.

Comment: Does having a vanity address (eg: 43COINxxxx at the beginning) decrease the security of the account? Does it increase its hackability by hostile parties?

Comment: You should ask this in a separate question, but I'm pretty sure no, it does not.

Comment: The go one works reasonably well. I generated my physical coins' addresses with it. The Javascript one is really slow, and won't be usable for very many characters.